# Intellij IDEA brown highlighted file name

Tags: intellij-idea

The intellij IDEA shows files and folders as not unversioned but they are already on the remote repository. Is it because these files are imported node modules? Or those these file color mean something else?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color is because the `nodes_modules` folder is marked as the `library root`.

Consider to remove the node_modules from source control. A general best practice is to keep the repository small and without dependencies. If you check in your `package.json` and `package-lock.json` anyone who checks out the repository can download the same dependencies and run your project.

This will keep the footprint of your repository small and tidy and makes it faster to download/process (i.e. in a build tool like jenkins).

Tip: after you've removed the node_modules add a `.gitignore` file to exclude it so it won't be accidentally checked in again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can you explain what `library root` means?

Comment: I suspect if you have npm/node support enabled, it will detect the node_modules folder automatically and mark it as library root. What it means is that it's used to determine the type of the folder. So it will use the sources inside it for autocompletion, but if you search for something, it will exclude it from your project (because it's not *your* source code). Otherwise you will get a lot of hits.

Comment: The folder icon is marked red, meaning it's excluded. Just like it will be marked green for test sources.